# Не обновляет данные в БД(PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Всем доброго времени суток.
Написал метод обновление данных,но почему то работает ооооочень криво
title = при отправке запроса меняет то 0,то 1
date,content = вообще не меняет
Тоесть,до Alert(Статья успешна обновлена); при изменение title доходит,но при изменение даты или контента - нет
Переменные передаются нормально,думаю в самом запросе запара.
Может кто помочь,заранее благодарю за ответы

```
 function EditArticle($db, $id, $title, $date, $content)
{
    $title = trim($title);
    $content = trim($content);
    $date = trim($date);
    $id = (int)$id;
    if (empty($title)) {
        return false;
    }
    try {
        $query = $db->prepare("UPDATE articles SET title = :title AND content =:content AND date = :date WHERE id=:id");
        $query->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $query->bindParam(':title', $title);
        $query->bindParam(':content', $content);
        $query->bindParam(':date', $date);
        $query->execute();
        echo "<script>alert('Статья успешна обновлена.');</script>";
        //header("Refresh: 0");
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Ошибка" . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: логично..... вы синтаксис UPDATE знаете? А я вам напомню:  посмотрите https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp   ..... http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/update.html

Comment: Похоже AND тут лишний.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неверный синтаксис SQL запроса. Верно будет

```
UPDATE articles SET title = :title, content =:content, date = :date WHERE id=:id
```

AND - это ЛОГИЧЕСКИЙ оператор и используется для составления условий в секции WHERE.